# Animate SVG Hamburger menu icon on click and keep it in :active state

Tags: svg, menu

I have a SVG hamburger menu icon that is animated when clicked. The goal is to transform it in to a "close" button when you activate the side-push menu. I need some help achieving that:

http://jsfiddle.net/a6ysa9zk/

HTML:

```
    <div class="toggle-menu menu-right push-body">

    <svg class="inline-svg" width="42px" height="42px" viewBox="0 0 42 42" enable-background="new 0 0 32 22.5" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
        <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.0.4 (8054) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
        <title>Group</title>
        <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
        <defs></defs>

        <g class="svg-menu-toggle" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
            <circle class="round" fill="#3B3B41" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="21" cy="21" r="21"></circle>
            <rect class="bar" fill="#F2F2F2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="12" y="26" width="18" height="4"></rect>
            <rect class="bar" fill="#F2F2F2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="12" y="19" width="18" height="4"></rect>
            <rect class="bar" fill="#F2F2F2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="12" y="12" width="18" height="4"></rect>
        </g>

    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.svg-menu-toggle {
    fill: #fff;
    pointer-events: all;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.svg-menu-toggle .round {
    transition: fill .4s ease-in-out;
}
.svg-menu-toggle .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
    transform: rotate(0) translateY(0) translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20px 10px;
    transform-origin: 20px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, fill .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, fill .4s ease-in-out;
}
.svg-menu-toggle .bar:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20px 10px;
    transform-origin: 20px 10px;
}
.svg-menu-toggle .bar:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20px 20px;
    transform-origin: 20px 20px;
}
.svg-menu-toggle:active .bar:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-10px) translateX(-8px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-10px) translateX(-8px);
    fill: #3B3B41;
}
.svg-menu-toggle:active .bar:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}
.svg-menu-toggle:active .bar:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(0px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(0px);
    fill: #3B3B41;
}
.svg-menu-toggle:active .round {
    fill: #F2F2F2;
}
```

Javascript for menu toggle:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.toggle-menu').jPushMenu();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the :active pseudo-element, its easier to add a class to the group (`.svg-menu-toggle`).
Unfortunately it isn't possible to use `toggleClass` from jQuery.

```
// CSS 
.svg-menu-toggle:active become .svg-menu-toggle.active

// JS
$('.toggle-menu').on('click', function(e) {
     var $toggle = $(this).find('.svg-menu-toggle');
     // toggleClass with addClass & removeClass
});
```